# Executing PHP code with HTML appear as text

Tags: php, html, mysql

hi i've aproblem with using php with html while i'm trying to execute php code at linux command line

```
#php code.php
```

it run properly but if i write the php code into html as

```
<html>
<body>
//php code
</body>
</html>
```

then run in browser the php code appear as text not executed

Comment: Is the html page with php extension?

Comment: Did you configure your web server to serve php pages?

Comment: in this case the file with html extension localhost/code.html 
when i've tried to browse localhost/code.php it appear nothing clear page 
----
i didn't change apache configuration i just installed php for linux then started apache service and tried the code.html which contain php and then the code appear as text

Comment: First Apache needs to be configured with php. Google for this. Second File extension needs to be php to be parsed by php before being issued to the browser. Then enable error reporting to see the issues in your php code.

Comment: ok first i've checked that apache2 configured to serve php 
second in web design i need to use html & css with php so the index file should be in html .. the problem clearly that php doesn't work with
<html> & <body>

Comment: A page with php extension is an html page that is pre-parsed by php and served as html to the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write code in php tag i.e. `<?php   ?>`

```
<html>
<body>
  <?php  //php code here  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

You can follow the [PHP Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_syntax.asp)

Comment: no problem in syntax cause i've tried the same code without html and it worked

Comment: ok, then you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page as  u_mulder is suggesting,

Comment: thank you so much i found that i should install php5-mcrypt for ubuntu